# Can we read cookies using core-java that has been written using .NET MVC code?

Tags: java, cookies, session-cookies, java-web-start

Can we read cookies using core-java, that has been written using .NET MVC code? I have not find any help how to read cookies using core java code?

More Background Details  -

Actually we have a java desktop application and we are planning to launch that java desktop application using JWS and that is working absolutely fine.

The issue is -- we ask some user related information from user on web page and launch java desktop application using JWS. Now we would like to have that information provided by user on web page in our java application.

We have write that information into cookies and how can we read that information from java code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can receive cookies that have been set by another application (as long as the path value in the cookie matches). Cookies are part of the HTTP protocol and it does not matter how thay were defined. The client sends them in future requests depending on the URL path.

To access cookies in Java, have a look at [getCookies()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getCookies%28%29) in HttpServletRequest.

**update**

The cookies set by your web-application that launches the Java client will have been set in the context of the browser client. Cookies are added to a HTTP response and cached by the client receiving them.

In the case that you describe you cannot access the same server-session from the Java client without trickery.

The solution I would use is to generate a unique ID in the web-app that is passed as argument to the Java client which can in turn request the values needed from the other session using a fetch of a URL using the generated ID as parameter. (This in essence connects the two HTTP sessions as being part of the same user process.)

For instance you could use a [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and a URL like `<web-app>/data?id=<ID>` to fetch/download the values as XML from your web application.

Comment: I have edited my original question. Will I am still able to read cookies using your suggestion?

Comment: Thank-you very-very much. It seems I am very near to the solution but I am finding difficulty to understand your suggestion in last paragraph. I understand only upto that unique ID will be passed as an argument to the java client. How can I request the values using that unique ID ? Can you please add some details? I am not completely understand how to get connect and get details ?

Answer (score 0):

Core-java? Then try java.net.*:
A cookie is just a header line with "Set-Cookie: " before the URL content.

http://www.hccp.org/java-net-cookie-how-to.html

Comment: I have edited my original question. Will I am still able to read cookies using your suggestion?

Comment: The server can use getCookies from the first answer. In the java webstart application you may use the code I pointed at. You cannot use the browser's cookie, as there is no secured relation to your jws app, browser and the server url. You might consider using the apache class HttpClient.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/cookie_support.html#cookie_support is probably the best way